# How to avoid install same instance of application wix installer MSI & EXE?

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, exe

I have an MSI & EXE installer that installs the excel plug-in. The user has option to download exe or msi to install the plug-in. The problem is my applicaiton shows a notification to user if new version of applicaiton is available and if user  get new version I always returns the msi file because at that point I don't have any information that user has installed the plug-in through msi or .exe. If user install thorugh exe and install new version with msi the multipe instance installed on same machine. How I can avoid it?

Also, is there any way in C# to know the applicaiton is installed through msi or exe?

Answer (score 0):

You should have two different `UpgradeCodes` - one for MSIs and one for EXEs. Then new version of MSI will replace MSI, EXE will replace EXE. Also don't forget to upgrade version number, or you will face same issue.

You can't upgrade EXE with MSI, they are treated by system as different products.

[How to find the UpgradeCode of installed app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936064/how-can-i-find-the-upgrade-code-for-an-installed-application-in-c)